# Why does Mockito call my matcher twice?

Tags: mockito

I've got a Mockito test that looks a bit like this (simplified, of course):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BlahTest {
    private static final int VERSION = 41;
    private static final int PAGE_SIZE = 4096;

    @Mock private FileChannel channel;

    @Test
    public void shouldWriteStandardHeader() throws Exception {
        final Blah blah = new Blah(channel, VERSION, PAGE_SIZE);
        blah.create();

        verify(channel).write(littleEndianByteBufferContaining(Blah.MAGIC_NUMBER,
                                                               VERSION,
                                                               PAGE_SIZE));
    }

    private ByteBuffer littleEndianByteBufferContaining(final int... ints) {
        return argThat(byteBufferMatcher(ints));
    }

    private Matcher<ByteBuffer> byteBufferMatcher(final int... ints) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<ByteBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(final Description description) {
                description.appendText("a little-endian byte buffer containing integers ").
                            appendValueList("", ",", "", ints);
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(final ByteBuffer buffer) {
                if (buffer.order() != ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN) {
                    return false;
                }

                for (final int i : ints) {
                    if (buffer.getInt() != i) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Essentially, this test is trying to assert that when `Blah.create()` is invoked, it writes a `ByteBuffer` containing certain data to the `FileChannel`.

When I run this test, the matcher gets called twice. This results in a `BufferUnderflowException`.

Now, I could get around this by just having the matcher store the buffer position at the beginning of the `matchesSafely` call and move the position back to that at the end (in a finally block), but it seems to me that my matcher shouldn't be being called twice.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

EDIT #1:

It's probably worth noting that the buffer is flipped before being passed to the channel, so the position is 0 and the limit is set to the amount of data written.

I've debugged the test, and the matcher is definitely getting called twice.

I can make the test pass by marking the buffer at the beginning of `matchesSafely()` and resetting it at the end, so the second pass through the matcher reads the same data. This also confirms that the matcher is getting called twice, as otherwise it would still fail.

EDIT #2:

So it looks like this is expected behaviour of the Mockito framework. In retrospect, my matcher is a bit poor because it modifies global state. I have modified the matcher to record the starting position and seek back to it at the end of the `matchesSafely()` method. This is probably a good idea anyway since it saves modifying global state. I don't use `mark()` and `reset()` for the same reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that your matcher gets called twice, you just have to `rewind` your buffer before reading from it:

```
protected boolean matchesSafely(final ByteBuffer buffer) {
    if (buffer.order() != ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN) {
        return false;
    }
    buffer.rewind();
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

So, appears it actually does get called twice.  It eventually it all happens in `verify` method. If you take a look at Mockito sources there is `Times.verify` method which is actually verifies 2 things:

1. if there are any missing invocations of the method
2. that the number of invocations of the method is exactly what is required

Mockito holds a list of actual invocations of all methods on your `channel` mock object. To verify which of these invocations are correct it matches every invocation with your matcher. And it actually does it twice. Please take a look at the sources to get the whole idea.

I'm not sure if it's a bug or not, you should ask Mockito devs. I suggest it won't hurt to `rewind` your buffer in the `matchesSafely` method every time to fix the problem - it should not hurt the correctness.

Comment: The buffer is rewound (well, flipped) before being passed to the channel. If it wasn't the channel wouldn't write anything at all. I did at least run the test through the debugger before I posted! The matcher is definitely getting called twice. First time through, it matches fine, second time the buffer underflows.

Comment: @dty my fault, it does invoke it twice - this is how Mockito works eventually, let me update the answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. I agree, that the matcher could be better. Ultimately it's modifying global state (i.e. the buffer position) which it probably shouldn't. If I make it record the position and move it back to where it started at the end of the matcher then all works fine, and we don't modify global state. I will make this a permanent change, I think.

Comment: Oh, and I don't think I should `reset()` or `flip()` the buffer inside the matcher because there's no reason to believe that the data which the `Blah` class wants written to the channel can be found at the beginning of the buffer.

Comment: @dty agree, saving and restoring position of the buffer seems like a better solution. cheers!

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to use `ArgumentCaptor` to verify argument to avoid custom matcher invoked twice.

```
ArgumentCaptor<ByteBuffer> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ByteBuffer.class);
verify(channel).write(captor.capture());
assertThat(captor.getValue().order(), equalTo(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN));
```

Comment: I believe this is most proper approach, at least for the problem author tries to solve.